# Exporting single band from multiband raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-3, band, data-management

In QGIS 3.16.8 I have a raster image in TIFF format which has 17 bands. I need to extract different band combinations as separate image files. Some of the combinations consist of images with single band only.

Is there a way in QGIS, where we can export a single band or combination of multiple bands as a image.

The gdal command cell input where I tried to translate raster layer and get the output is not working for me. I have attached the image for your reference.[image]

Comment: What is your QGIS version? Maybe 3.10?

Comment: I have updated the question title, its 3.16.8

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a trick to solve your problem.

From the top menu, go to Raster>Conversion>Translate.

Then, in the Translate window, perform the following tasks:

1. Select your input layer.
2. Select the output path and write an output file name.
3. Choose target SRS (desired output coordinate reference system).
4. After performing the above steps, you will see the command at the bottom (inside a text box).
5. Edit this command, and add "-b 1" at the end if you want to extract the first band from the input image. Add "-b 2" if you want to extract the second band, and so on.

For example (To extract the first band):

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff "path of input image" "path of output image" -b 1
```

For example (To extract the first two bands):

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff "path of input image" "path of output image" -b 1 -b 2
```

In this way, you can extract different bands and their combinations from an input image.

For more description, visit the [documentation](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html).

Comment: I tried to follow the steps you have mentioned however, I am not able to succeed. GDAL cell is not allowing me to place additional input i.e., '-b 1 or -b 1 -b 2' - I am not able to insert there in the cell.  I am attaching the image of gdal console cell in the question description.

Comment: In your gdal console cell, there is a textbox to add additional command line parameters. Use it to add required parameters.

Comment: Hi Srinivas, I have the same issue, not able to edit the GDAL console. Could you let me know how you solved it?

Comment: See the previous comment. I Hope, it will help you.

Comment: At 3.22.3, you cannot edit the text within the *GDAL/OGR console call* box.  Instead, enter your additional input, such as **-b 1** in the *Additional command-line parameters [optional]* box.  Notice how this edits the *GDAL/OGR console call*

Answer (score 9):

Use raster calculator - it has all the individual bands as inputs. Select the band you want as the only term in your expression and save it

Comment: Much easier, thank you for the trick @Jane

Comment: Do you know how to "call" all of the bands, i have 2160?

Comment: In Raster Calculator, the items list in Raster Bands are individual whole rasters, each (potentially0 containing multiple bands. If one selects (double click) the raster they want, its full name is populated in quotes in the raster calculator expression. How does one select one or more bands from that specific raster (and have it output)? Thanks