Importing DTM from WMS
I used a GetMap request to query a DTM layer (French national DTM coverage called RGE ALTI) in GeoTIFF format. However the resulting layer has 3 bands instead of one. My end goal is to visualize it in Qgis2threejs (https://github.com/minorua/Qgis2threejs), but it doesn't appear as a DEM layer. Anyone has had a similar issue?



By the documentation https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/IGN_RGE_ALTI_1M_2_0#bands there are 3 bands in the dataset, and the height in meters is stored into the first band.

MNT (band 1) Terrain elevation in meters.
SRC (band 2) The main source of the data used to calculate the altitude of the node.
DST (band 3) The distance in meters between the node and the nearest point used to calculate its altitude.

Open the properties of the image layer and change the rendering to use only the first band. Maybe that makes the layer usable for qgis2threejs.

If qgis2threejs still does not accept the layer, extract the first band into a new physical image file. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/404813/30184 for how to.
However, if you have acquired the GeoTIFF from a WMS service it may be that it is just a rendered 8-bit image of the DEM and in that case it is not usable as DEM. You will need the original, probably 16-bit data instead. Without more information it is impossible to know what kind of data you have in your hands.

I think the GeoTiff I acquired is 8-bit. I tried the maneuver that was used in https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/404813/30184 to try and extract the band 1 but I get a storage warning : Input file size is 1073741824, 1073672680
ERROR 3: band1_rge_alti.tif: Free disk space available is 158189391872 bytes, whereas 1152847261802168320 are at least necessary. You can disable this check by defining the CHECK_DISK_FREE_SPACE configuration option to FALSE..

I'm interested to hear how I can get the original 16-bit one if you don't mind elaborating on that

A web search, found this site https://geoservices.ign.fr/rgealti.
I downloaded one .7z file and there seems to be 32 bit ascii grid files in the MNT directory.

I extracted the band 1 using raster calculator and it is not detected as a DEM by Qgisthreejs. You're right, i need the original one. My end goal however makes it difficult for me to use it (to download each departement DEM). I'm developping a QGIS plugin that gives the user the possibility to choose a bounding box and get corresponding rasters in that extent, which is why WMS works fine for me.

For the DEM to be displayed in Qgis2threejs, I needed to extract the first layer of the output I get from the WMS GetMap request, then output the file as .geotiff locally.
